# DisallowedHost at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header:

Tags: python, django, iis, deployment, windows-server-2012-r2

I am getting `Error DisallowedHost at /`

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: `'subdomain.example.com'`. You may need to add 'subdomain.example.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

in my Django project which is deployed on IIS Windows server. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes it throws an error. Even I have set `DEBUG = False.` I got an error page as it appears in DEBUG = True mode.

Sometimes It works fine, and sometimes it throws an error. I have already added my subdomain i .e (`subdomain.example.com`) in ALLOWED HOSTS in settings.py.

Please help me to solve this problem permanently.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'yourdomain.com']
```

in the settings file, basically every domain you are going to run your web app from needs to be in this ALLOWED_HOSTS, I would suggest you to make a different settings file for development, production etc.

Comment: I have already set it but it runs sometimes and gives error other time. Even though I have set debug=False it shows the Error page as in debug=True mode.